# how to test rooted application on adt emulator?

Tags: android

As you can understand from title, I have made an application which uses sudo command in its one method. I, now, want test this application on Android. As I understand, emulator is not rooted. Thus, I have some questions;

- In ADT, is there a way to make ADT emulator as being rooted? If yes, how?
- If no, without needing to use physical device, how can I test my application?

Note: can you give your answer step by step ? (first do then ... )

Thanks

Comment: Which emulator version are you trying to root?

Comment: @RaghavSood I have installed two days ago from Android website. I assume it is last version. But, how can I learn its versio?

Comment: I meant which version of Android is it running.

Comment: @RaghavSood I have not found a way. Is the way rooting the emulator forbidden or imposible? ( I thougt Google may prefer to restrict user )

Comment: It is possible, but I don't know how to do it for 4.2. Try [this](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-hacks/127518-how-root-get-root-access-android-emulator.html).